# How to interpret analogy of Gaussian integral of Alien Copies in IUT theory by Mochizuki?

Tags: number-theory, gaussian-integral, teichmueller-theory

In Mochizuki's paper, he refers to copy of Integral as 'Alien Copy', which is strange since the double integral is an extension of the surface of uni-dimensionnal integral due to Summation properties (linearity)...

Can anybody explain why 'Alien Copy' means in Gaussian integral computation ?

THE MATHEMATICS OF MUTUALLY ALIENCOPIES: FROM GAUSSIAN INTEGRALS TO
INTER-UNIVERSAL TEICHMULLER THEORY

http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~motizuki/Alien%20Copies,%20Gaussians,%20and%20Inter-universal%20Teichmuller%20Theory.pdf

EDIT: 
To be precise, this is not very clear what can be considered as alien and as not-alien.

For example if we have :

```
I= Integral(gaussian(x) dx,-inf, inf)
J= Integral(gaussian(x/2) dx,-inf, inf)
```

are I and J are aliens ?

and what about

```
K= 2*Integral(gaussian(x) dx, 0, inf)  ?
```

Comment: Related question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/245438/mochizukis-gaussian-integral-analogy

Comment: It's a metaphor, not a precise mathematical statement.  Don't take it too seriously.

Comment: ...Ok (the reasoning of the theory is far from obvious...., this is not clear where the metaphor stops ... and the logical reasoning follows/begins...

Comment: I don't think you grasp the metaphor: when investigating $\int f(x)\text d x$ we can introduce a copy $\int f(y)\text d y$ which is the same thing as the first one, but put together in an equation the manipulations on the second has nothing to do with the first one.

Answer (score 2):

You could always read the paper you linked a bit closer: he says, in the very first mention, that

> common features that underlie these analogies may be summarized as
>   follows:
>
> - the introduction of **two mutually alien** copies of the object of    interest;
> - the computation of the effect — i.e., on the two mutually alien copies of the object of interest
> - etc

he then continues to explain what he means:

> Here, the intended sense of the descriptive “alien” is that of its
>   original latin root, i.e., a sense of abstract, tautological
>   “otherness”

So, in essence, he means that you introduce a copy of the thing that is "alien", as in that it is exactly the same but formally a different thing. Are you familiar with the calculation he refers to? It involves introducing the same integral once again but with another variable, making the two integrals "mutually alien".

---

edit: I also found this quote from 1.3 of the paper relevant and quite entertaining:

> Here, let us recall that our hypothetical high-school student was
>   already in a mental state of extreme frustration as a result of the
>   student’s intensive and heroic attempts in Step 2 which led only to an
>   endless labyrinth of meaningless and increasingly complicated
>   mathematical expressions. This experience left our hypothetical
>   high-school student with the impression that the Gaussian integral was
>   without question by far the most difficult integral that the student
>   had ever encountered.
>
> Step 3 evoked a reaction of intense indignation and distrust on the
>   part of the student. That is to say, the idea that meaningful progress
>   could be made in the computation of such an exceedingly difficult
>   integral simply by considering **two identical copies** of the integral —
>   i.e., as opposed to a single copy — struck the student as being
>   utterly ludicrous.In light of this experience, the suggestion of

Comment: "Alien" looks like more a "language term" rather a mathematical definition.

Comment: Is that a problem?

Comment: Suppose you have I=J=K ,  3 integrals having the same values,  are they aliens each other ?

As the definition looks ambiguous, the analogy looks ambiguous..., ie, it can be used as an example to show his IUT calculation, this is not clear at which level the analogy is same / (not exactly same).

Comment: I think it could be a bit naïve to expect an analogy between multi-variable calculus and Theta-elliptic NF-hodge theaters and log-theta-lattices to be straightforward.

Comment: Looks like studying the interplay between numerical and generic alterity.

Comment: @SylvainJulien thanks for this highly valuable comment, which was illuminating, on-topic, and posted just at the right time.